# PyPDF2 is not adding pages

Tags: macos, pdf, pypdf

I have a bunch of worksheets as pdfs. There are 2 pages in each pdf. The first page of the pdf is the actual worksheet. And the 2nd one is the answer. I wanted to put all of the actual worksheets into a pdf called `worksheets.pdf`, and another to contain the answers in `answers.pdf` I tried with the work shown below but it always printed out the last page of all the pdfs. I am currently on mac.

```
import PyPDF2

def separate_worksheets_and_answers(pdf_path, worksheets_pdf_path, answers_pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
        writer_worksheets = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        writer_answers = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        for page_number in range(reader.numPages):
            page = reader.getPage(page_number)
            if page_number % 2 == 0:
                writer_worksheets.addPage(page)
            else:
                writer_answers.addPage(page)

        with open(worksheets_pdf_path, 'ab') as worksheets_file:
            writer_worksheets.write(worksheets_file)

        with open(answers_pdf_path, 'ab') as answers_file:
            writer_answers.write(answers_file)


for i in range(1, 26):

    pdf_path = f"Week 2/{i}.pdf"
    worksheets_pdf_path = "Week 2/worksheets.pdf"
    answers_pdf_path = "Week 2/answers.pdf"

    separate_worksheets_and_answers(pdf_path, worksheets_pdf_path, answers_pdf_path)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file in Append Mode (AB) instead of Write Mode (WB) in the separate_worksheets_and_answers function, which overwrites the previous change and only works on the last page.

Comment: I changed it to `wb` but it still didn't work